# Detect if a QPushButton is being clicked

Tags: qt, events, user-interface, click, qwidget

I'm trying to find out whether a button is being pressed or not from within the paintEvent(), so that I can draw the "down" state. However, I don't know where to find this information. I tried QStyleOptionButton::state but it doesn't tell whether the button is being clicked or not.
The output of the debug statement is always something like "QStyle::State( "Active | Enabled | HasFocus | MouseOver" )" so nothing about a MouseDown state.

```
void XQPushButton::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event) {
    QPushButton::mousePressEvent(event);

    QStyleOptionButton options;
    options.initFrom(this);
    qDebug() << (options.state);
}


void XQPushButton::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) {
    QPushButton::paintEvent(event);

    QStyleOptionButton options;
    options.initFrom(this);
    qDebug() << (options.state);
}
```

So any idea how I can detect if the button is being clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QPushButton` inherits `QAbstractButton`, which provides [the `down` property](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractbutton.html#down-prop):

> This property holds whether the button is pressed down.

The documentation of the `QStyleOption` parent class contains [an example that uses this property](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstyleoption.html#details):

```c
void MyPushButton::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QStyleOptionButton option;
    option.initFrom(this);
    option.state = isDown() ? QStyle::State_Sunken : QStyle::State_Raised;
    //...
}
```

In other words, the sunken/raised state is not initialized by `initFrom()`. This makes some sense, since `initFrom` is [inherited from `QStyleOption` and takes a `QWidget`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstyleoption.html#initFrom):

```
void initFrom ( const QWidget * widget )
```

– and a generic `QWidget` has no notion of "raised" or "sunken".

At least this is how I read the docs.